# Trace console.info from stacktrace

Tags: javascript, debugging, stack-trace

I would like to trace where the console.log() or console.warn or console.info was called. I looked stacktracejs and other library as reference, however most of them are showing example of error. I would like to trace back to where the info/log/warn is originated from.

any pointers?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to trace where the console.log console.warn or console.info are called, then try using Chrome and viewing in the developer console. The console will show what file and line the output originated.

Comment: Thanks Jack.. I am actually writing library with basic information. So when customer uses my library, they will say 
 function init () {
 log.info("Loading init", App is now been loaded...")
}

inside my log library I will like to give them trace where this .info came from

Comment: I am writing a library which is does similar thing as stacktracejs, trackitjs and stuff. However mine is very simple, The way user will use my library is  'log.inf(), log.warn(), log.error()', etc... For error I know we can trace information from error.stack. How to achieve same thing for warning and info...  hope I am making sense